# Very slow key generation on certain OS versions with SpongyCastle

Tags: android, security, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am building an app in which I use the spongycastle library (which is run-down version of bouncycastle), but the problem is when I perform this:

```
KeyParameter key = (KeyParameter) generator.generateDerivedMacParameters(keyLength * 8); // key length in bits
```

and build it on any phone which has API of 6.0 or below the operation is extremely slow. To pinpoint the exact code which runs very slow (note that this code is in spongy library):

```
for (int count = 1; count < iterationCount; count++)
    {
        hMac.update(state, 0, state.length);
        hMac.doFinal(state, 0);

        for (int j = 0; j != state.length; j++)
        {
            out[outOff + j] ^= state[j];
        }
    }
```

The iteration count is always 800000 because I need it to be very secure, but the process to execute this code takes almost 5 minutes on these devices. The interesting part is that on API 4.4 it only takes about a minute. So, is there any workaround for this without reducing the iteration count, maybe I should just use bouncycastle or something else?

Comment: Spongycastle is not a "run-down" version of bouncycastle, it is a full version of bouncycastle that has changed a few package names to avoid conflicts with earlier Android versions.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake on my part, didn't read that quite thoroughly. But it isn't getting updated, on the other hand bouncy is so its still not full version of bouncy.

Comment: **If** this is PBKDF2 then yes, there may be ways of speeding it up, but please indicate if this is the algorithm first ... Note that Bouncy (Spongy) is a SW only library, and Java will generally not match a good C implementation for crypto ops, let alone a C implementation with hardware support. I.e. if you can keep to the security providers in Android then you should.

Comment: Yes, I am using PKCS5S2 which is defined by PKCS 5 V2.0 Scheme 2 [link](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.html). Also, what do you mean by SW-only library ? While searching through the internet I found that Argon2 is even better so maybe I should migrate to using it instead?